# how do I attach a watcher to each element in an array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a bunch of js objects in an array.
I want to add a watch to every item in the array.
So that I can send out a change, and the desired item will turn on, while others will turn off.

Or is that too expensive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Vue 3 it's common to use composition API which has a different syntax than options one :

```js
import {watch, ref} from 'vue'
...
const items=ref([])

watch(items,(newVal,oldVal)=>{
    //do something
},{
  deep:true
})
```

if the array is not a `ref`, the first parameter is a callback function that returns the property :

```js
import {watch} from 'vue'
...
...

watch(()=>props.items,(newVal,oldVal)=>{
    //do something
},{
  deep:true
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `deep` property for that problem like so

```
new Vue({
  ...
  watch: {
    things: {
      handler: function (val, oldVal) {
        console.log('a thing changed')
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  ...
})
```

You can read more about that topic [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers)